# React Code Splitting dynamic import typescript interface

Tags: typescript, code-splitting-async

Is there any way to use dynamic import('path') for an exported interface?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you've tried that hasn't worked please Domenico?  Also it seems like this question is independent of using React?  Anything that depends on an interface would be effected no?

Comment: My was just a question for better understanding code splitting.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to code splitting in interface because all typescript will be compiled into plain javascipt during build time.

Comment: Thanks.
According to your answer I've found this:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-imports-being-elided-in-my-emit